# В laravel изменить заголовок Content-Type при отображении sitemap

Tags: laravel

На сайте есть `sitemap`

Он состоит из `индекса Sitemap` и множества файлов с перечислением ссылок (в каждом файле по 50к ссылок).

Индекс sitemap разместил в папку public.

Доступ к индексу по ссылке: `example.com/sitemap.xml`
Доступ к другим файлам:

- `example.com/sitemap/sitemap1.xml`
- `example.com/sitemap/sitemap2.xml`

Файл открывается, но в заголовке ответа `Content-Type: application/xml`.
Мне нужно изменить Content-Type на другой ответ.
Подскажите как можно реализовать?

Если бы я генерировал средствами laravel sitemap, то проблем бы не было. Просто в Response прописал нужный заголовок.

Но нужно прямой ссылкой вывести файл индекса сайтмапа и файлы с перечислением ссылок. Как в таком случае можно изменить Content-Type?

Comment: А Laravel тогда тут при чём, если Вы напрямую файл вытаскиваете? Меняйте заголовки через веб-сервер (Apache/Nginx)

Comment: Или создавайте роут, ставьте заголовок и отдавайте весь файл через file_get_contents. Но это должна быть не прямая ссылка на файл...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Спасибо) что то неподумал, что за этоно apache отвечает